# Internet Explorer is copying hidden table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using jquery command found in the following jfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/3uu0tpv1/2/

Namely, I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table#safe-distances-table').dblclick(function () {
        $('tr.no-impact').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

To cause some rows in an HTML table to toggle off when the table is double clicked. Jquery is working fine, but my real problem is copying and pasting from Internet Explorer.

I am limited to using Internet Explorer in some enviornments and **I am expecting that when rows are hidden and I copy and paste the table from I.E. to Outlook, the hidden rows will not come with it. Instead, they are!**

You can try in the JFiddle with Internet Explorer. After double clicking on the table, try copying and pasting the full table into Outlook and you will see all the rows appear!

Comment: It's copying the HTML, not the rendering.

Comment: Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, actually [copies _multiple_ things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx) to the clipboard when you copy — it will generally have both the HTML and the final rendered text _both_ on the clipboard. How does it know what to _paste?_ In MS-Word it's configurable and changeable, but in general `Ctrl+V` (nowdays) pastes with formatting... but try `Shift+Ctrl+V` to [paste without formatting](http://www.howtogeek.com/186723/ask-htg-how-can-i-paste-text-without-the-formatting/).

Comment: The thing is, I actually do want the formatting -- but only the formatting of the visible output! Can I get the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested in IE - this should work in theory.

You'll need to [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the hidden rows before you copy them. It makes putting the rows back on double click a little bit fiddly - you'll need to keep track of the original data before you remove them.

[This fiddle seems to do the trick.](https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/3uu0tpv1/5/) It keeps hold of the original HTML, and whether we're in a 'toggled' state using [$.data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

```
$('table#safe-distances-table').dblclick(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    if($el.data('toggled')){
        $el.html($el.data('all'));
        var $rowsToHide = $('tr.no-impact');
        $rowsToHide.hide();
        $rowsToHide.toggle('slow');
        $el.data('toggled',false);
    } else {
        var $rowsToHide = $('tr.no-impact');
        $el.data('all', $el.html());
        $rowsToHide.toggle('slow', function(){
            $rowsToHide.remove();
        });
        $el.data('toggled',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: In jquery, is there an event handler for the copy-paste functionality? Perhaps that is when I could do the .remove() function?

Comment: There is - `$(el).on('copy', function(){ ... });`. But I don't see why you'd bother - the above snippet should do the trick. Once the elements are hidden (`display:none;`), you mayaswell remove them (in this case. There might be other times where you want to keep a hold of the elements on the DOM, just not have them visible - I don't think this is one of them.)

_Edit - glad it works :o)_