# Variable Not Remembering Itself When Separating Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scope

As an extension to my previous question and this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327605/1582712), I am trying to modulate my JavaScript code so I utilize the same double click functionality across other classes.

My code is in the following [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/5Lzr8p7p/)

If you try double clicking the H3 or the table, they don't seem to come back. I believe the reason is because the `$el` variable is not being registered and/or remembered properly.

I have a tried a few things, such as returning the `$el` variable and reusing it. I tried using an array for `$el[search]` so each is unique. None worked. I'm a little stumped, I think its a subtle JavaScript memory issue here!

FYI:
If you run this [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/3uu0tpv1/7/) You'll see the double clicking works over and over again. I am hoping to get this same effect, but generalized to any html class/id in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not only hiding the elements but also removing them from the DOM (line 25 in your JSFiddle).  After removing them you are also calling `hide` (line 17) and then `toggle` (line 18) but the elements do not exist to `hide` or `toggle` anymore.  You can resolve the problem by removing `$rowsToHide.hide();` (line 17) and `$rowsToHide.remove();` (line 25).  [See this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lzr8p7p/1/).  This will hide the elements but not remove them from the DOM.

Comment: Although that does work, it does go against another issue I have described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327241/internet-explorer-is-copying-hidden-table-elements?lq=1) Basically, when I only hide the element and don't remove it, a copy/paste into Outlook results in the hidden elements to be placed into a pasted email.

Answer (score 1):

This is not right:

```
$('table#safe-distances-table').dblclick(function () {
    handleDoubleClick('tr.no-impact');
});

function handleDoubleClick(search) {
    var $el = $(this);
    // rest of the code
}
```

Try to do this:

```
$('table#safe-distances-table').dblclick(function (evt) {
    handleDoubleClick(evt.currentTarget);
});

function handleDoubleClick(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    // rest of the code
}
```

You have to pass the clicked element, not a selector to search and modify... its not the same thing. Be careful becase this evt.currentTarget means the element the user clicked. Maybe you must capture the parent element (.parent()) in order to get all the data, but ALWAYS try to send the event... and then with currentTarget obtain the clicked element.

ENJOY!

Comment: You are doing a .remove() instead of .hide()... if you want to remove, first save the data... and create again the elements when you want to show.

Comment: @Lkwieder, if that were true, why would this work perfectly in my referenced jfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/3uu0tpv1/7/)

Comment: Also, I implemented your code in the first jfiddle and I noticed it works perfectly for the table but  not the h3! (https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/5Lzr8p7p/2/)

Comment: There are to separate things:
In the callback, when you call a function passing a selector, you have to find the element/s with that selector, and then do something.. if you pass the event, you can obtain exactly the clicked element, not matter if is an H3, DIV, etc. Maybe then you have a little extra work looking for the parent... or something, its on you.

The other thing is, the .remove and .hide... you don't want to hide, because the copy paste thing. Try to save your data in a variable OUTSIDE the scope, and then remove.

Comment: Weird, when I up the scope, it still doesn't work. Think you see why? https://jsfiddle.net/esend7881/5Lzr8p7p/3/